# Show that the function $f: [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f: [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
0,&\text{if } 0 \le x < \frac{1}{2}\\
1,&\text{if }\frac{1}{2} \le x \le 1\;.
\end{cases}$$

I need to show that this function is integrable, and my instructor says if we consider the partition $P = (P_1, P_2)$ where $P_1 = P_2 = \{0, \frac{1}{2}, 1\}$, then $U(f, P) = L(f,P) =  \frac{1}{2}$, but this is clearly false since

$$U(f, P) = (1/2)^2 + (1/2)^2 + (1/2)^2 + (1/2)^2 = 1$$

and

$$ L(f, P) = 0 + 0 + (1/2)^2 + (1/2)^2 = 1/2.$$

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: We don't even have a partition the way it is defined

Comment: I think $P$ is a partition of $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$

Comment: Jean-Sébastien is right. Specifying a grid is not a description of partition

Comment: I understand that your partition is supposed to be 4 squares, but you need explcitly and very carefully describe all this 4 squares. Some of them will contain their boundary, others doesn't

Comment: I interpret what I see as cutting into four equal squares.

Comment: But what about bounadries of this squares. It is important for computation of $U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)$

Comment: I learned that a partition of a rectangle $[a_1, b_1] \times...\times [a_n, b_n]$ is a collection $P = (P_1,...P_n)$ where $P_i$ is a partition of the interval $[a_i, b_i]$

Comment: So the subrectangles of my partition will be $[0, \frac{1}{2}] \times [0, \frac{1}{2}], [0, \frac{1}{2}] \times [0, 1], [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$, and $[0, 1] \times [0, \frac{1}{2}]$

Comment: Take a slightly finer partition that encloses the line $\{\frac{1}{2}\} \times [0,1]$ in a rectangle of area $< \epsilon$. Then it should be straightforward? The only issue is this line, which has content 0.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try the simpler one-dimensional integral $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$ with piecewise defined function:

$$ f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & x > 1/2 \\ \\ 0 & x < 1/2 \end{array} \right. $$

---

Use the partition $[0, 1/2 - \epsilon]\cup [1/2 - \epsilon, 1/2 + \epsilon] \cup [1/2 - \epsilon, 1]$.  Then

$U(f,P) = 0\cdot (1/2 - \epsilon) + 2\epsilon\cdot1 + 1 \cdot(1/2 - \epsilon)= 1/2 + \epsilon $
$L(f,P) = 0\cdot (1/2 - \epsilon) + 2\epsilon\cdot0 + 1 \cdot(1/2 - \epsilon)= 1/2 - \epsilon $

Then we have upper and lower bound for the integral:
\[ 1/2 - \epsilon <  \int_0^1 f(x) dx < 1/2 + \epsilon  \]

---

This can be extended to 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Take 
$$
P_1=[0,\frac{1}{2})\times[0,1], P_2=[\frac{1}{2},1]\times[0,1].
$$ 
Then 
$$
U(f,P)=|P_1|\sup_{P_1}f+|P_2|\sup_{P_2}f=|P_2|=\frac{1}{2}, \ L(f,P)=|P_1|\inf_{P_1}f+|P_2|\inf_{P_2}f=|P_2|=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: In my question $P_i$ are partitions of the interval and not subrectangles, but I see what you did.  So you can just throw out the endpoint and call $[0, \frac{1}{2} ) \times [0, 1]$ a subrectangle?

Comment: @WacDonald's I don't know which definition you're using, but your function is clearly a simple function, in fact it is the characteristic function of $[1/2,1]\times[0,1]$.